# Syntax error in huge SQL file: How to find it?

Tags: sql-server, syntax, sqlcmd

I am executing a very big (3 gigabytes) SQL file via the command line. It is too big to be opened in the SQL Server Management Studio. After several minutes, the tool returns a syntax error.

```
Msg "102", Level "15", State "1", Server "XYZ\XYZ", Line 20 "Unclosed
quotation mark after the character string "text3
"."
```

Please note the line break after `"text3`!

**My question is:** How can I find the location of the error?

I need to somehow search the big file. Preferarbly with `vim`. However, I have no idea how to look for that error. The text `text3` appears many times in the file. As said, I cannot open the file in the SQL Server Management Studio. The error is also not in Line 20. So I am not sure what that `Line 20` in the error message even means? Maybe I can somehow make use of that line break.

Comment: Line 20 probably means a query's 20'th line.

Comment: there are no queries exceeding 20 lines. maybe a query batch is meant.

Comment: Open the file and search for `"text3"`.

Comment: As I said: `The text text3 appears many times in the file.` => Hence, this is no option.

Comment: Use a profiler and check last successful batch. Line 20 of the next batch will have the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have big file with small batches you will launch SQL Server Profiler (SSMS Menu Tools) choose Events about Errors and Profiler catch text of batch with error. And you can find bad batch.[image: profiler window]

Answer (score 0):

My solution to similar issues is divide and conquer. 
Split the file into halves on a command border i.e. ';' 
Try to execute first half, then the second. 
Repeat the halving in the offending file until the haystack is small enough to see the needle.

Sometimes the chopping is enough to make the problem go away.